Visualize species occurrence similarities of 5x5 grid-cells and soil samples in R
I have two data frames:

ref_df containing for each row information about species and the latitude and longitude they was recorded and

sample_df with sample names as rows and species names as columns, and each cell being 1 (present) or 0 (absent).


I now wanted to bring the ref_df and its coordinates into a 5x5 Km grid and get a presence/absence dataframe similar to my sample_df. So each row being a distinct coordinate pair and the columns being the species names, with cells being agin, 1 or 0.
I then calculate the Dice-Sorensen coefficient of each grid-cell and each sample based on their species composition. However when I plot the grid-cells I get these very strange vertical lines of cells that show a super low similarity. Is this due to my way of creating the 5x5km grid?
When I transform the ref_df as described, I get it to this form:

which is great because the calculation of the similarity coefficient between the ref_df and the sample_df

works perfectly. The issue is the actual plotting:
grid_size <- 1/22.2 # for geeting 5x5km
ref_df<- ref_df%>%
  mutate(lon_grid = floor(lon / grid_size) * grid_size + grid_size/2,
         lat_grid = floor(lat / grid_size) * grid_size + grid_size/2)

Calculation of similarity then plotting:
# Getting the border of Switzerland
    ch_map <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", country = "Switzerland", returnclass = "sf")

# Converting the sorensen similarity results to sf
    grid_cells_sf <- st_as_sf(sorensen_mean, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
    grid_ch <- st_intersection(grid_cells_sf, ch_map)`

# Plotting similarity on map
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = grid_ch , aes(color = sorensen_sim), shape = 15, size = 2) +
      scale_color_viridis_c(option = "viridis") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.title = element_blank())+
      labs(color = "Similarity", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")


The issue disappears if I take larger grids e.g. 8x8 Km

Seems your "grid" is made of squares plotted by ggplot: shape = 15, size = 2. I would suggest to create spatial grid with st::st_make_grid() function and assign the values to the grid itself, like:
ch <- geodata::gadm("CH", level = 0, path = "data")

ch <- ch |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:21781")

ch_gr <- sf::st_make_grid(ch, cellsize = c(5000, 5000)) |>
  sf::st_sf() |>
  sf::st_filter(ch)

Now let's simulate a bit of species occurence in Switzerland:
occurence <- sf::st_sample(ch, size = 10000) |>
  sf::st_sf()

And assign the count to ch_gr grid.
ch_gr$count <- lengths(sf::st_intersects(ch_gr, occurence))

In your case I would intersects ch_gr with ref_df to have occurence/absence of species per grid.
tmap::qtm(ch_gr, fill = "count")



library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ch_gr , aes(color = count)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "viridis") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",axis.title = element_blank())+
  labs(color = "Count", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")


Created on 2024-12-10 with reprex v2.1.1

Okay thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense. But so now, using this approach, how would it be best to calculate the similarty e.g. dice sorensen between each 5000x5000m gridcell and my sample dataframe "sample_subset"?

Would you mind to share the samples of your data frames, please? dput(head(ref_df )) , the same for sample_df and include the calculation of Dice-Sorensen coefficient as well. You may edit your question and include the data.
